# How to make code navigation work for a Python project in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, code-navigation

I have locally cloned the Tensorflow github project https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow

I am using VSCode since it seems to be the recommended IDE. One feature that will make it easier for me to explore the code is "click to navigate" (i.e when I click on function it navigates to its definition).

Currently click to navigate works if function is in the same file but not if the definition is in another file.  How do I make this work on VSCode?

Comment: Are you using VSCode to open the whole folder, as opposed to a single file?

Comment: Did you install the python extension?

Comment: in VScode, just to this:  right click on the function and select "Go to Definition" (or `f12` keyboard shortcut).

Answer (score -1):

In vscode, even if you only open a single file, the target file of navigation can be navigated successfully in the same folder by using shortcuts <kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Click.

You can read document about **[Go to Definition](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_go-to-definition)**.

I think the only possibility is that you haven't installed the [Python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python).

You can also read the [Python-tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial) for more details.